# how to take input of C program in sublime text 3?

Tags: c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d\n",n );
    return 0;
  }
```

When I write this code in SUBLIME text 3 it shows error like:

```
/../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file demo.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 3.1s]
```

What is the problem?

Comment: What is `demo.exe` file? and what is access rights on this file? From error log it seems that issue is related to  access right on file `demo.exe`.

Comment: What OS are you using? Clearly it is Windows, but what version? What is the name of the file you save? What are the exact steps you follow after you save this file?